# How to change Google Docs specific section margins using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am attempting to change the margins of the first section of a Google Doc, however the code below is applying this to the whole document:

```
    // Insert section break at the beginning of the document
    const resource = {requests: [{insertSectionBreak: {sectionType: "NEXT_PAGE", location: {index: 1}}}]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, docId);
    
    var body = doc.getBody();
    body.setMarginTop(0);
    body.setMarginLeft(0);
    body.setMarginRight(0);
    body.setMarginBottom(0);
```

Is there a way to apply margin settings to a specific section of the document?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from `change the margins of the first section of a Google Doc`. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Hello Tanaike, nice to hear from you! The fact is that through Google Docs user interface, one can: create a section break (from the menu: Insert, Break, Section break), then apply margins to a given section, however this may not be exposed within the API. So for instance, assuming a document has two sections , is there a way to programmatically apply margins only to one section of the document?

Comment: From your reply, I thought that I might be able to understand your expected result. So, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the margin of one of the multiple sections in a Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

When I checked this, unfortunately, I couldn't find the built-in method of Document service (DocumentApp)for achieving your goal. But, fortunately, it seems that this can be achieved by Google Docs API. In this case, I would like to propose the sample script using Docs API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sectionNumber = 1; // 1 is the first section.

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const docId = doc.getId();
  const obj = Docs.Documents.get(docId, { fields: "body(content(sectionBreak,startIndex,endIndex))" }).body.content.filter(e => e.sectionBreak);
  const section = obj[sectionNumber - 1];
  if (!section) {
    throw new Error(`No section of ${sectionNumber} is not found.`);
  }
  const { startIndex, endIndex } = section;
  const requests = [{
    updateSectionStyle: {
      range: { startIndex: startIndex || 0, endIndex },
      sectionStyle: {
        marginLeft: { unit: "PT", magnitude: 0 },
        marginRight: { unit: "PT", magnitude: 0 },
        marginTop: { unit: "PT", magnitude: 0 },
        marginBottom: { unit: "PT", magnitude: 0 }
      },
      fields: "marginLeft,marginRight,marginTop,marginBottom"
    }
  }];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the margin of the 1st section is changed.
- Please adjust the margen of `sectionStyle` to your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSectionStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatesectionstylerequest)

Comment: Tanaike, you are a genius! I vote for you as president of Japan! Thank you again!